# Can't change title/caption of shared links (was possible with old interface)

Tags: facebook, hyperlink, sharing, editing, caption

I run a page for a Russian company, and I often have to fix the grammar in titles of my links. This was possible in the old interface - by clicking on the title in the post-preview, etc. But now I cannot do this, as there is no title given in the preview.
Will the old functionality be restored?

Thank you,
Ciaran

Comment: Facebook deprecated this feature ...